# Merge two 2d arrays by shared column value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, merge

I know this is quite easily accomplished with a `foreach`, then a `while`->list, etc procedure, (I have already accomplished it), however I sense that my code is a bit dirty and it doesn't look like the best solution... I'm looking to use native PHP array functions to do the following:

I have two arrays that look like this:

```
[
    ['rank' => '579', 'id' => '1'],
    ['rank' => '251', 'id' => '2'],
]
```

and

```
[
    ['size' => 'S', 'status' => 'A', 'id' => '1'],
    ['size' => 'L', 'status' => 'A', 'id' => '2'],
]
```

And I need merge them to produce:

```
[
    ['size' => 'S', 'status' => 'A', 'id' => '1', 'rank' => '579'],
    ['size' => 'L', 'status' => 'A', 'id' => '2', 'rank' => '251'],
]
```

Is there a way to be able to merge two arrays with the `id` value (or any other) without going into a endless set of `foreach`s?

Comment: Are elements with the same id at the same index in both arrays? In other words, if the element with id 5 is at index 3 in the first array, will it also be at index 3 in the second array?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [array_merge_recursive()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php)

```
$array = array_merge_recursive($array1, $array2);
```

or make your own function (it may be faster)

```
function my_array_merge(&$array1, &$array2) {
    $result = Array();
    foreach($array1 as $key => &$value) {
        $result[$key] = array_merge($value, $array2[$key]);
    }
    return $result;
}
$array = my_array_merge($array1, array2);
print_r($array);
```

Comment: Awesome!, thanks for this, FYI: the function approach works excellent as long as you need to discard those records that do not repeat on both arrays.

Comment: This doesn't technically answer the question. @OsvaldoM. wants to join based on the value of id, not by the keys.

Answer (score 6):

As Ray noticed in a comment, the accepted answer does not actually answer the question. I was unable to find an answer, so I created the following small utility function:

```
function array_merge_callback($array1, $array2, $predicate) {
    $result = array();

    foreach ($array1 as $item1) {
        foreach ($array2 as $item2) {
            if ($predicate($item1, $item2)) {
                $result[] = array_merge($item1, $item2);
            }
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Use it as follows:

```
array_merge_callback($array1, $array2, function ($item1, $item2) {
    return $item1['id'] == $item2['id'];
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a nice one to merging arrays like another languages.
It's because php have auto numbering array elements, and merging will dublicate or replace different elements by keys.

Now, it's changed.

```
// array_fork
  public static function array_fork() {
    $args = func_get_args();
    $result = array();
    foreach ($args as $arr) {
      is_array($arr) || exit('[' . __METHOD__ . '] Each item must be an array.');
      foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
        if (is_array($val)) {
          // recursion
          !isset($result[$key]) && $result[$key] = array();
          $result[$key] = self::array_fork($result[$key], $arr[$key]);
          continue;
        }
        if (is_numeric($key)) {
          if (!in_array($arr[$key], $result))
            $result[] = $arr[$key];
        } else
          $result[$key] = $arr[$key];
      }
    }
    return $result;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function custom_array_merge(&$array1, &$array2) {
    $result = Array();
    foreach ($array1 as $key_1 => &$value_1) {
        // if($value['name'])
        foreach ($array2 as $key_1 => $value_2) {
            if($value_1['name'] ==  $value_2['name']) {
                $result[] = array_merge($value_1,$value_2);
            }
        }

    }
    return $result;
}
```

// Pass $array1, &$array2 and change the $value_2['name']  // name based on which u want to merge.

Comment: This question doesn't have a `name` column.

Answer (score 1):

ok, let's suppost your arrays are called $arr1 and $arr2, you could do this:

```
<?php
$newarray = Array();
foreach ($arr1 as $element=>$value){
    $newarray = array_merge($arr1[$element],$arr2[$element])
}
?>
```

Comment: This approach is ignoring the `id` values.  It is simply merging on first level indexes (which is only correct by coincidence because the [mcve] is not strong enough to expose this inappropriate logic).

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to use a recursive technique nor multiple loops.  Merge the two arrays together, then assign temporary first-level keys in the output array based on the rows' `id` value.  If the `id` is being encountered for the first time, merge the row's data with an empty array; otherwise merge the pre-existing row data from result array.  To remove the first-level keys after looping, call `array_values()`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ncfvc))

```
$a = [
    ['rank' => '579', 'id' => '1'],
    ['rank' => '251', 'id' => '2'],
];

$b = [
    ['size' => 'S', 'status' => 'A', 'id' => '1'],
    ['size' => 'L', 'status' => 'A', 'id' => '2'],
];

$result = [];
foreach (array_merge($a, $b) as $row) {
    $result[$row['id']] = $row + ($result[$row['id']] ?? []);
}
var_export(array_values($result));
```

---

Not represented by the question's sample data, if the two data sets have columnar data collisions in their respective `id` group, then later encountered values will overwrite earlier stored values.  [Demo](https://3v4l.org/2JX4G) To reverse that behavior, you can simply swap the data on either side of the "array union operator". [Demo](https://3v4l.org/vhFiW)  Be warned that array union is suitable in this case because the rows contain non-numeric keys.  For other scenarios, it may be more reliable to use `array_merge()` or `array_replace()` instead of the union operator.