# Replace multidimensional array that has the same key values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this array that I have to replace the values according to their id. below is the `Original Array`:

```
 [
  0 => [
    "id" => "70"
    "color" => "red"  
  ]
  1 => [
    "id" => "65"
    "color" => "blue"
  ]
  2 => [
    "id" => "66"
    "color" => "black"
  ]
  3 => [
    "id" => "73"
    "color" => "red"
  ]  
]
```

And this is the array that I need to insert and replace the array that has the same `id` in the original array:

```
  0 => [
    "id" => "65"
    "color" => "white"  
  ]
  1 => [
    "id" => "66"
    "color" => "gold"
  ] 
]
```

What I am trying to achieve is something like this:

```
     [
  0 => [
    "id" => "70"
    "color" => "red"  
  ]
  1 => [
    "id" => "65"
    "color" => "white"
  ]
  2 => [
    "id" => "66"
    "color" => "gold"
  ]
  3 => [
    "id" => "73"
    "color" => "red"
  ]  
]
```

Comment: This question is resolved [this way](https://3v4l.org/EihRo) as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74767958/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution with `array_column` and `array_walk` functions:

```
// $arr1 is the original array
// $arr2 is the replacing array

$colours = array_column($arr2, "color", "id");

array_walk($arr1, function(&$v) use($colours){
    if (array_key_exists($v["id"],$colours)) {
        $v["color"] = $colours[$v["id"]];
    }
});

print_r($arr1);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 70
            [color] => red
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 65
            [color] => white
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 66
            [color] => gold
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 73
            [color] => red
        )
)
```

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-column.php

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-walk.php

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
<?php
$original = [
  0 => [
    "id" => "70",
    "color" => "red"  ,
  ],
  1 => [
    "id" => "65",
    "color" => "blue",
  ],
  2 => [
    "id" => "66",
    "color" => "black",
  ],
  3 => [
    "id" => "73",
    "color" => "red",
  ]  
];

$toReplace =   [0 => [
    "id" => "65",
    "color" => "white"  ,
  ],
  1 => [
    "id" => "66",
    "color" => "gold",
  ] 
];

function getColorByKey($key, $toReplace)
{
    $result = null;
    foreach($toReplace as $k => $value)
    {
        if($value['id'] == $key)
            $result = $value['color'];
    }

    return $result;

}


foreach($original as $key => $value)
{
   $newColor = getColorByKey($value['id'], $toReplace);
    $original[$key]['color'] = $newColor !== null ? $newColor : $original[$key]['color'];
}

var_dump($original);
```

Output of `var_dump`:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "70"
    ["color"]=>
    string(3) "red"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "65"
    ["color"]=>
    string(5) "white"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "66"
    ["color"]=>
    string(4) "gold"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "73"
    ["color"]=>
    string(3) "red"
  }
}
```

There is a function `getColorByKey($key, $toReplace)` which is used in `foreach` loop, where `$key` is `id` index, and `$toReplace` is your second array.

Comment: thank you, your code works. However we can learn from RomanPerekhrest answer <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36197141/replace-multidimensional-array-that-has-the-same-key-values/36198154#36198154>  which is the simplest I guess.

Answer (score 1):

```
// $array1 = original array
// $array2 = second array

foreach ($array1 as $key1 => $value) 
{
    $new[$value['id']] = $key1;
}

foreach ($array2 as $value) 
{
    if (array_key_exists($value['id'], $new))
    {
        $key2 = $new[$value['id']];
        $array1[$key2]['color'] = $value['color'];
    }
    else
    {
        $array1[] = array('id' => $value['id'], 'color' => $value['color']);
        // if this color not present, then it adds this to the original array 
    }
}

echo '<pre>'; print_r($array1);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 70
            [color] => red
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 65
            [color] => white
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 66
            [color] => gold
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 73
            [color] => red
        )

)
```