# How to get common element within the array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with some indexes and i want to get the common element.
**Array**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [Code] => A
                [Price] => 2333
                [Item] => [Item_0_1]
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [Code] => C
                [Price] => 2000
                [Item] => [Item_0_2]
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [Code] => F
                [Price] => 655
                [Item] => [Item_0_3]
            )
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [Code] => C
                [Price] => 7632
                [Item] => [Item_1_1]
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [Code] => D
                [Price] => 2334
                [Item] => [Item_1_2]
            )
    )
)
```

So what i have to do as per above array there is two nested index `[0]` and `[1]`, it can be more. 
so i have to get common element based on code from both index array as you can see there are only one element common which is `[Code] => C`, so i have to get this element from both array but common array will like

```
[Code] => A // that will be same 
[Price] => 9632 // [0]...[Price]+[1]...[Price]
[Item] => [item_0_3,item_1_2] // this will push in array
```

**Output i want like this**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Code] => C
            [Price] => 9632
            [Item] => [item_0_3,item_1_2]
        )
)
```

so how to make new array with the common array i have tried `foreach, array merge` and more but failed i am not be able to make logic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_merge_recursive()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php), it would look something like this:

```
$merged_array = array_merge_recursive($array1, $array2);
```

To get the result similar to:

```
array(2) { 
    [0]=> array(1) {
        [0]=> array(3) {
            ["Code"]=> string(1) "A"
            ["Price"]=> string(4) "2333"
            ["Item"]=> string(8) "Item_0_1"
        }
    }
    [1]=> array(1) {
         [0]=> array(3) {
             ["Code"]=> string(1) "A"
             ["Price"]=> string(6) "121212"
             ["Item"]=> string(8) "Item_0_3" 
         }
    }
}
```

Then you can loop through your array as normal:

```
for($i = 0; $i <= count($merged_array) -1; $i++) {
    echo ($merged_array[$i]['Code'] == "A") : $merged_array[$i]['Price'] . ' + ' : "";
}

// Output: 2333 + 121212
```

> To do this with your own code, check out this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7973997/5897602).

Comment: Well, the recursion works by matching the same keys to the same values, so as long as your data holds this continuous pattern: this will work for you. @User97798

Answer (score 0):

This will help you to get your result..

```
$array; //<----- Your input array

$code_array = array();
foreach($array as $key => $row) {
    if($key == 0) {
        $code_array = array_column($row,'Code');
    } else {
        $code_array = array_intersect($code_array, array_column($row,'Code'));
    }
}
//You will get common element code in $code_array variable

$result_array = array();
foreach($code_array as $key => $code) {
    $result_array[$key] = array(
        'Code' => $code,
        'Price' => 0,
        'Item' => ''
    );
}
// Created Result array with unique codes

foreach($array as $row) {
    foreach($row as $sub_row) {
        $key = array_search($sub_row['Code'],$code_array);
        if($key) {
            $result_array[$key]['Price'] += $sub_row['Price'];
            $result_array[$key]['Item'] .= $result_array[$key]['Item'] == '' ? $sub_row['Item'] : ','.$sub_row['Item'];
        }
    }
}
//Assigned values to result array
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple method:

```
function merge_duplicates(array $array) {
    $newarr = [];
    foreach ($array as $arr) {
        foreach ($arr as $elem) {
            if (!isset($newarr[$elem['Code']])) {
                $newarr[$elem['Code']] = $elem;
                $newarr[$elem['Code']]['Item'] = [$elem['Item']];
            } else {
                 $newarr[$elem['Code']]['Price'] += $elem['Price'];
                 $newarr[$elem['Code']]['Item'] = array_merge($newarr[$elem['Code']]['Item'], [$elem['Item']]);
            }
        }
    }
    return array_values($newarr);
}

echo print_r(merge_duplicates($mi));
```

It return the whole list of items, but those that are duplicate will be merged into one, adding the price and making a list of Item name or whatever it is.