# Replacing values in an array basing on values from another

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, optimization, laravel-5.1

Having the 2 following arrays:

```
[
    {"id":1,"value":40},
    {"id":2,"value":30}
]
```

And:

```
[
    {"userId":1,"worth":20},
    {"userId":2,"worth":10}
]
```

What I want to have in the end, is the following result:

```
[
    {"id":1,"value":20},
    {"id":2,"value":10}
]
```

So here, I want to replace in the first array, the values with those in the second array, according to the ìd`. I made something like that:

```
foreach ($array2 as $k => $v) {
    array_filter($array1), function($item) use($value) {
        $item['id'] == $v['userId'] ? $item['value'] = $v['worth'] :$item['value'] = $item['value'];
    });
}
```

It is working for those given arrays, but if you have arrays with more than 1 million data, it will never be done !
The question is, if there are some PHP functions which can do this hard work?

### Update

The arrays format is updated and now I should use the following format:

```
[
    0 => stdClass {"id":1,"value":40},
    1 => stdClass {"id":2,"value":30}
]
```

And:

```
[
    0 => Statement {"userId":1,"worth":20},
    1 => Statement {"userId":2,"worth":10}
]
```

### Result of Var_dump:

Array 1:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[2721]
      public 'value' => float 84
      public 'id' => int 1229
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[2707]
      public 'value' => float 144
      public 'id' => int 1712
```

Array 2:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    object(Bank\Accounting\Statement)[2754]
      public 'worth' => float 572
      public 'userId' => int 1229
  1 => 
    object(Bank\Accounting\Statement)[2753]
      protected 'worth' => float 654
      protected 'userId' => int 1712
```

Comment: need some more information please .. are you using laravel .. i saw the laravel tag

Comment: yes I am working with Laravel 5.1

Comment: Maybe with `array_map` you can do it?

Comment: Are the 2 arrays on the same order always?

Comment: @MickaelLeger that is what I tried, but I couldnt'

Comment: @Eddie no they don't have the same order, should I maybe order it first?

Comment: Look this question maybe : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973915/php-merge-arrays-by-value, but can't see an anwser that php will do itself right now, maybe it's possible must most anwser use custom function

Comment: @MickaelLeger in question you sent, he is trying to merge 2 arrays, for my case it is `replacement` more than merging

Comment: @MosCH You're right, but I have no idea what's faster :1/ You merge 2/ You replace or 1/ You check if common value 2/ You replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array_column` to make the `userId` as the key and `worth` as the value.

Use `map` to reiterate the first array. Check if the key exist, if exist replace the `value`.

```
$arr1 = [{"id":1,"value":40},{"id":2,"value":30}];
$arr2 = [{"userId":1,"worth":20},{"userId":2,"worth":10}];

//Use array_column to make the userId as the key and worth as the value.
$arr2 = array_column($arr2, 'worth', 'userId');


//Use `map` to reiterate the first array. Check if the key exist on $arr2, if exist replace the `value`. If not replace it with empty string.
$results = array_map( function($v) use ( $arr2 ) {
    $valueInArr2 = array_search($v->id, array_column($arr2, 'userId'));
    $v->value = $valueInArr2 ? $valueInArr2 : "";
    return $v;
}, $arr1);


echo "<pre>";
print_r( $results);
echo "</pre>";
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [value] => 20
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [value] => 10
        )

)
```

---

**Update:** Using Object. I have not tested this.

```
$arr1 = .....;
$arr2 = .....;

//Make the object into array
$arr2 = array_reduce($arr2, function($c,$v) {
    $c[ $v->userId ] = array(
        'worth' => $v->worth;
        'userId' => $v->userId;
    );
    return $c;
},array());

//Update the first array
$results = array_map( function( $v ) use ( $arr2 ) {
    $val = array( 'id' => $v->id );
    $val['value'] = isset( $arr2[ $v->id ] ) ? $arr2[ $v->id ] : "";
    return $v;
}, $arr1);
```

Comment: array_column return an empty array

Comment: Can you post on how you used your `array_column`?

Comment: I made: $array2 = array_column($array2,'worth','useId');

Comment: Seems that your array format has changed. Can you `var_dump` those array and post value instead?

Comment: @MosCH Please check

Comment: `isset( $balances[ $v->id ] ) ? $balances[ $v->id ] : ""` will not work with objects, but your solution is good !

Comment: Yeah you are right. You might need to use `array_reduce` @MosCH

Comment: `array_search($v->id, array_column($arr2, 'userId'))` does the work ;)

Comment: Ohh okay. Great if it works for you. But you will search every reiteration.

Comment: hmm that is what I don't want, but I can't see another way for the moment..

Comment: `$val = array( 'id' => $v->id );
    $val['value'] = isset( $arr2[ $v->id ] ) ? $arr2[ $v->id ] : "";` why you do it if you will `return $v` in all the ways?

Comment: Ohh no. That was a typo. That should be val.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167331/discussion-between-mosch-and-eddie).

Answer (score 1):

you can try this way (using laravel collection):

```
$arr1 = '[{"id":1,"value":40},{"id":2,"value":30}]';
$arr2 = '[{"userId":1,"worth":20},{"userId":2,"worth":10}]';

$arr1 = json_decode($arr1, true);
$arr2 = json_decode($arr2, true);
$col2 = collect($arr2);

foreach ($arr1 as &$value) {
    $value['value'] = $col2->where('userId', $value['id'])->first()['worth'];
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr1);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [value] => 20
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [value] => 10
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

After building a simple associative lookup/dictionary array, loop over the first array, modify the `value` elements by reference, and update the values if the id is found in the lookup.  If the id is not found, leave the original value.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/NhO39))

```
$arr1 = json_decode('[{"id":1,"value":40},{"id":2,"value":30}]', true);
$arr2 = json_decode('[{"userId":1,"worth":20},{"userId":2,"worth":10}]', true);

$lookup = array_column($arr2, 'worth', 'userId');
foreach ($arr1 as ['id' => $id, 'value' => &$value]) {
    $value = $lookup[$id] ?? $value;
}
var_export($arr1);
```