# Compare 2 jsons and add missing elements in both jsons with default value in php

Tags: php, json, laravel

I have 2 Jsons ,i need to compare both the Jsons and add missing elements in one json with default value.
I have tried the below code but its merging both the Jsons.

a=[{"id":1,"name":"test1"},{"id":"2","name":"test1"},{"id":"3","name":"test1"}];
b=[{"id":2,"count":10},{"id":"3","count":11},{"id":"4","count":13}];

expected output
a=[{"id":1,"name":"test1"},{"id":"2","name":"test1"},{"id":"3","name":"test1"}];
b=[{{"id":1,"count":0}}{"id":2,"count":10},{"id":"3","count":11},{"id":"4","count":13}];

return json_encode(
array_merge(
json_decode($a, true),
json_decode($b, true)
)
);

Comment: [Replacing values in an array basing on values from another](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49424381/2943403) looks topical.

Answer (score 0):

here I have updated code . that use laravel collection

```
   <?php
    
    
    $a = '[{"id":1,"name":"test1"},{"id":"2","name":"test1"},{"id":"3","name":"test1"}]';
    $b = '[{"id":2,"count":10},{"id":"3","count":11},{"id":"4","count":13}]';
    
    // Convert the JSON strings to arrays
    $a = json_decode($a, true);
    $b = json_decode($b, true);
    
    $a = collect($a);
    $b = collect($b);
    
    
    // run with transform function thats in laravel collection
    $a->transform(function ($aItem) use ($b) {
        $rtnItem = $aItem;
        foreach ($b as  $bItem) {
    
            if ($bItem['id'] == $aItem['id']) {
                foreach (collect($bItem)->keys() as $key) {
                    if (!collect($aItem)->has($key)) {
                        $rtnItem[$key] = $bItem[$key] ?? null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    
    
        return $rtnItem;
    });
    
    
    echo json_encode($a);
```

Comment: Sorry, its giving count=0 for all the ids

Comment: check now i have updated code