# PHP how to remove duplicate or equal array value and append the data in an array

Tags: php

I have an array with 4 data each, what i want to accomplish is to remove
value of duplicate/equal tag_id and put/append the tag_images together
of the same tag_id. I also used array_unique but i don't know where to put it.

My array has a tag_id,tag_slug,tag_color, and tag_images(array). The last 2 array have the same data except with tag_images, I want to merge those data as one and put the tag_images in an array. 
example:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["tag_id"]=> int(25)
    ["tag_slug"]=> string(5) "green"
    ["tag_color"]=> string(7) "#81d742"
    ["tag_images"]=> array(1) {
      [0]=> string(75) "http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/long-sleeve-tee.jpg"
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["tag_id"]=> int(23)
    ["tag_slug"]=> string(3) "red"
    ["tag_color"]=> string(7) "#dd3333"
    ["tag_images"]=> array(1) {
      [0]=> string(69) "http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/vneck-tee.jpg"
    }
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["tag_id"]=> int(23)
    ["tag_slug"]=> string(3) "red"
    ["tag_color"]=> string(7) "#dd3333"
    ["tag_images"]=> array(1) {
      [0]=> string(66) "http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/beanie.jpg"
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["tag_id"]=>
    int(25)
    ["tag_slug"]=>
    string(5) "green"
    ["tag_color"]=>
    string(7) "#81d742"
    ["tag_images"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(75) "http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/long-sleeve-tee.jpg"
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["tag_id"]=>
    int(23)
    ["tag_slug"]=>
    string(3) "red"
    ["tag_color"]=>
    string(7) "#dd3333"
    ["tag_images"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(66) "http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/beanie.jpg"
      [1]=>
      string(69) "http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/vneck-tee.jpg"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: We can't help you if you don't show us what you've tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd iterate the main array and build a second one.

```
$mainArray = array
(
    array("tag_id"      => 25,
        "tag_slug"      => "green",
        "tag_color"     => "#81d742",
        "tag_images"    => array("http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/long-sleeve-tee.jpg")
    ),
    array("tag_id"      => 23,
        "tag_slug"      => "red",
        "tag_color"     => "#dd3333",
        "tag_images"    => array("http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/vneck-tee.jpg")
    ),
    array("tag_id"      => 23,
        "tag_slug"      => "red",
        "tag_color"     => "#dd3333",
        "tag_images"    => array("http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/beanie.jpg")
    )
);

$freshArray = array();
foreach ($mainArray as $value)
{
    $key = array_search($value['tag_id'], array_column($freshArray, 'tag_id'));
    if (false === $key)
        $freshArray[] = $value;
    else
        $freshArray[$key]['tag_images'][] = $value['tag_images'][0];
}
var_dump($freshArray);
```

Output :

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      'tag_id' => int 25
      'tag_slug' => string 'green' (length=5)
      'tag_color' => string '#81d742' (length=7)
      'tag_images' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/long-sleeve-tee.jpg' (length=70)
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      'tag_id' => int 23
      'tag_slug' => string 'red' (length=3)
      'tag_color' => string '#dd3333' (length=7)
      'tag_images' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string 'http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/vneck-tee.jpg' (length=64)
          1 => string 'http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/beanie.jpg' (length=61)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_merge_recursive()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php)

Or use this function from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7973997/10303343)

```
function my_array_merge(&$array1, &$array2) {
    $result = Array();
    foreach($array1 as $key => &$value) {
        $result[$key] = array_merge($value, $array2[$key]);
    }
    return $result;
}
$array = my_array_merge($array1, array2);
print_r($array);
```