# How to merge two arrays by value in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

If I have two super-simple arrays, as such:

```php
$a = [1, 2, 3];
$b = [2, 3, 4, 5];
```

How do I combine them so that the result is a single array without duplicate values? i.e.,

```php
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

I would have thought this could be handled with a simple function like `array_merge()` or `array_replace()`, but those operate on *keys* in an associative array. I need them to go by *value*. I don't care about the indices in the array and I can always sort it by value if I need to using one of the many sorting methods provided by PHP.

The same problem exists with Laravel's Collections: `->merge()`, `->concat()`, `->replace()`, `->union()`, etc. don't work on values at all.

It seems incredibly inefficient to me that the only way to accomplish this is to write several lines, including a `foreach()` loop with `if()` conditions inside that use `in_array()` to decide whether or not to add each value from the second array to the first.

Is there a better way?

**Edit 09/08/2022**: Although this question was initially flagged as [a duplicate of another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973915/php-merge-arrays-by-value), the accepted answer to that question [never actually answered the OP's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973915/php-merge-arrays-by-value#comment34021827_7973997) and, by extension, my own question of how to sort by *value*. In addition, the accepted answer of "use array_merge_recursive()" does not, by itself, answer my question. Finally, the question in that post involves an associative array, whereas my question disregards keys entirely. Thus, the reason why I posted this question and do not consider it a duplicate.

Comment: have you tried to do a merge then get the unique values with the helper methods/functions?

Comment: `array_merge` does not operate on the keys.

Comment: @apokryfos From [the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php): "If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value for that key will overwrite the previous one. If, however, the arrays contain numeric keys, the later value will not overwrite the original value, but will be appended."

Comment: @Sturm If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later **value** for that key will overwrite the previous one. If, however, **the arrays contain numeric keys, the later value will not overwrite the original value, but will be appended.** Your case is entirely the 2nd case, and even if you had an associative array, what is merged are the values not the keys

Comment: @apokryfos It's _almost_ the second case. I want the values to be truly _merged_, not just _appended_, so my point still stands that it cannot "be handled by a simple function like `array_merge()`" by itself. Yes, I was probably incorrect in using the word "operate" since it does merge values even though it still looks for keys. I just conveniently left out the second case in my original paragraph because, again, it doesn't _merge_ non-associative arrays, just concatenates them. I was under the impression that there must be a single, simple function that could handle my use case.

Comment: I think it's a difference between what data structures. Your arrays are a simple [array data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure), PHP also supports [associative arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) however you want your data to operate like a [set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type)) and you want a set union but PHP does not have a set data structure implementation for values, though the keys of an associative array behave like a set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use array_unique() & array_merge() to merge and remove duplicates :

```
$a = [1, 2, 3];
$b = [2, 3, 4, 5];
$array = array_unique(array_merge($a, $b));
// output [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Arr::collapse](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-array-collapse) to combine multiple array and use `array_unique` to remove duplicate and use `array_values` for reindexing

e.g.

make sure to include `Arr` helpers

```
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
```

then

```
$array = Arr::collapse([ [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4, 5]]);

return array_values(array_unique($array ));
```

Comment: Although not as succinct as the other answers, this one is still quite helpful and a unique way of tackling the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
Type-1: (Array Merge)

$array1 = [1, 2, 3];
$array2 = [2, 3, 4];

$finalArray = array_merge($array1, $array2);

// output [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4]

Type-2: (Unique array after merge)

$array1 = [1, 2, 3];
$array2 = [2, 3, 4];

$finalArray = array_unique(array_merge($array1, $array2));

// output [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: 'Type-2' is the way to go for my case. Thank you so much!