# Merge 2 arrays with diffrent keys based on a shared key's value

Tags: php, arrays

How can I merge 2 different arrays with different keys based on a shared key's value?
I am trying to keep as basic the first array.
If in the second array, shared key's(Mark) value is the same, merge with first array.

**First array:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [IssueDate] => 2024-01-22
            [Mark] => 400001923264133
            [Vat301] => 0
            [Vat331] => 0
            [Vat302] => 0
            [Vat332] => 0
            [Vat303] => 0
            [Vat333] => 0
            [Vat304] => 0
            [Vat334] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [IssueDate] => 2024-01-22
            [Mark] => 400001923536194
            [Vat301] => 0
            [Vat331] => 0
            [Vat302] => 0
            [Vat332] => 0
            [Vat303] => 0
            [Vat333] => 0
            [Vat304] => 0
            [Vat334] => 0
        )

)
```

**Second array:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [uid] => 0D7F298912F21E7934380E5728AEF6E31AB74E3F
            [Mark] => 400001923264133
            [vn] => 094019245
            [series] => 0
            [aa] => 396663852
            [name] => string
                (
                    [name] => TYPE_2_1
                    [value] => 2.1
                )

            [netValue] => 976.15
            [vatAmount] => 246.50
            [vatCategory] => int
                (
                    [name] => VAT_1
                    [value] => 1
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [uid] => 0D7F298912F21E7934380E5728AEF6E31AB74E3F
            [Mark] => 400001923536194
            [vn] => 094019245
            [series] => 0
            [aa] => 396663852
            [name] => string
                (
                    [name] => TYPE_2_1
                    [value] => 2.1
                )

            [netValue] => 976.15
            [vatAmount] => 246.50
            [vatCategory] => int
                (
                    [name] => VAT_1
                    [value] => 1
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [uid] => 74820E25D29945A74408F64FCBEAE229D4D386FF
            [Mark] => 400001923801925
            [vn] => 094019245
            [series] => 0
            [aa] => 396663852
            [name] => string
                (
                    [name] => TYPE_2_1
                    [value] => 2.1
                )

            [netValue] => 976.15
            [vatAmount] => 246.50
            [vatCategory] => int
                (
                    [name] => VAT_1
                    [value] => 1
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [uid] => F218FCCF5A12CA067221D4C783ABC52B0A305ACA
            [Mark] => 400001924018534
            [vn] => 094019245
            [series] => 0
            [aa] => 396663852
            [name] => string
                (
                    [name] => TYPE_2_1
                    [value] => 2.1
                )

            [netValue] => 976.15
            [vatAmount] => 246.50
            [vatCategory] => int
                (
                    [name] => VAT_1
                    [value] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

I want to add to first array, second array's keys and values if key['Mark'] contains the same value.

**Expected Output
Third array:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [uid] => 0D7F298912F21E7934380E5728AEF6E31AB74E3F
            [vn] => 094019245
            [series] => 0
            [aa] => 396663852
            [name] => string
                (
                    [name] => TYPE_2_1
                    [value] => 2.1
                )

            [netValue] => 976.15
            [vatAmount] => 246.50
            [vatCategory] => int
                (
                    [name] => VAT_1
                    [value] => 1
                )       
            [IssueDate] => 2024-01-22
            [Mark] => 400001923264133
            [Vat301] => 0
            [Vat331] => 0
            [Vat302] => 0
            [Vat332] => 0
            [Vat303] => 0
            [Vat333] => 0
            [Vat304] => 0
            [Vat334] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [uid] => 0D7F298912F21E7934380E5728AEF6E31AB74E3F
            [Mark] => 400001923536194
            [series] => 0
            [aa] => 396663852
            [name] => string
                (
                    [name] => TYPE_2_1
                    [value] => 2.1
                )

            [netValue] => 976.15
            [vatAmount] => 246.50
            [vatCategory] => int
                (
                    [name] => VAT_1
                    [value] => 1
                )       
            [IssueDate] => 2024-01-22
            [Mark] => 400001923536194
            [Vat301] => 0
            [Vat331] => 0
            [Vat302] => 0
            [Vat332] => 0
            [Vat303] => 0
            [Vat333] => 0
            [Vat304] => 0
            [Vat334] => 0
        )

)
```

Comment: is this php or js? looks more like php to me. Wrong question tag

Comment: It is php. My bad. thanks for pointing it out. I changed tag to php.

Comment: Doesn't `array_merge($array1, $array2);` worked for you?

Comment: @YoushaAleayoub That doesn't merge recursively.

Comment: @YoushaAleayoub And before you guess to use `array_merge_recursive()`, that's not correct either. It uses the array indexes to find common elements, but they want to do it based on the value of the `Mark` keys.

Comment: Change the first array so the keys are the `Mark` values. Then loop through the second array, using `array_merge_recursive()` to merge each element into the corresponding value in the first array.

Comment: This is relevant but does not filter out the unused elements of the second array: [Merge two 2d arrays by shared column value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7973915/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be a few ways to do this, but I'll demonstrate the use of references.  Ideally, you should not perform nested loops or use more than two loops.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/0oLKP))

```
// create references for each row of the first array
foreach ($first as &$row) {
    $ref[$row['Mark']] =& $row;
}

// prepend data to any second array data that matches the Mark value
foreach ($second as $set) {
    if (isset($ref[$set['Mark']])) {
        $ref[$set['Mark']] = $set + $ref[$set['Mark']];
    }
}

// The first array is mutated to include desired data from the second array
var_export($first);
```

---

If you want to avoid using references and are happy to generate a third array, you can create a lookup array from the first array then merge qualifying data from the second array with the relevant lookup element when pushing into the result array. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/KU2uV))

```
$result = [];
$lookup = array_column($first, null, 'Mark');
foreach ($second as $set) {
    if (isset($lookup[$set['Mark']])) {
        $result[] = $set + $lookup[$set['Mark']];
    }
}
var_export($result);
```